# How to animate the HTML contents using jquery..

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTMl texts that is getting changed dynamically.Now as per my requirement i have to display them in animated form like fading and in some motion but i am not aware of this ..
Here is my Code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var v = {};
        v[0] = "Your Text<br/>Hello";
        v[1] = "Your Text2<br/>Hello2";
        v[2] = "Your Text3<br/>Hello3";

        var i = 0;

        window.setInterval(function () {
            $("#dynamicMessage").html(v[i]);
            if (i == 2) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i = i + 1;
            }

        }, 10000);
</script>
```

Please have a look and let me know how can i animate my text contents in HTML..
Thanks..

Comment: There is a fadeIn, fadeOut effect in jQuery you can use that.  it's a animation for show/hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`

```
$("#dynamicMessage").fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    $("#dynamicMessage").html(v[i]).fadeIn('slow');
})
```

Check this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/xw2j6hsp/1/

**UPDATE**

Saw this comment, on @laruiss answer:

> "If there are other way by which i can show the text popping from the
>   left"

Thought i'd code this up for you. Just add in some animation. check it - http://jsfiddle.net/m6bnq1ja/

Answer (score 1):

There's no animating the content change. What you can do is hide the element, change its content, then fade it in, something like below. It'll probably look the same to the user.

```
$("#dynamicMessage").hide().html(v[i]).fadeIn();
```

or

```
 $("#dynamicMessage").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).html(v[i]).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to clearTimeout (or clearInterval)

```
var v = [
        "Your Text<br/>Hello",
        "Your Text2<br/>Hello2",
        "Your Text3<br/>Hello3"
    ],
    i = 0,
    timeout = null,
    change = function (text) {
        var $dynamicMessage = $("#dynamicMessage")
            .fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $dynamicMessage.html(text).fadeIn();
            });
        if (i == 2) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {change(v[i]);}, 2000);
    }
change(v[i]);

$(window).unload(function() {window.clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = null;});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u41pkxk1/)

Comment: Thanks ..Its working ..If there are other way by which i can show the text popping from the left and animating slowly as it is shown in your fiddle

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but with jQuery UI you can use the slide effect : http://jsfiddle.net/u41pkxk1/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
 var v = {};
    v[0] = "Your Text<br/>Hello";
    v[1] = "Your Text2<br/>Hello2";
    v[2] = "Your Text3<br/>Hello3";

        var i = 0;
        window.setInterval(function () {
        $("#dynamicMessage").fadeToggle( "slow", function() {
            $("#dynamicMessage").html(v[i]).fadeToggle('slow');
        });
        if (i == 2) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }, 4000);
```

Note : you can also use "fadeOut" & "fadeIn" in place of "fadeToggle"